# Access apps inside an app

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS development, suppose I'm making an app for parental control over their kids which would have the apps that would be added by the parent so that the child is restricted to only certain apps. How will i access the apps on the device inside this app?

Comment: Can't be done. One app can't in any way restrict other apps.

Comment: You don’t need an app to do this - [iOS has built-in parental controls](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but that won't be possible on an standard (un-jailbroken) iOS device.  Apple sandboxes Apps so they can't access anything outside of their "sandbox".  That includes the file system, the OS, settings and other apps on the device.

It might be possible to do it on a jailbroken iOS device, but even then you'll have to hack into Apple's OS and honestly it's probably not worth the effort, especially given that you could never submit such an app to the app store..